# Cannot populate required constructor argument error

Tags: flutter, dart

the provided is my code

```
@freezed
@JsonSerializable()
abstract class MovieItemDto implements _$MovieItemDto {
  const MovieItemDto._();
  const factory MovieItemDto(
      {required String id,
      required String body,
      required int color,
      required bool done}) = _MovieItemDto;

  factory MovieItemDto.fromDomain(Movie movie) {
    return MovieItemDto(
        id: movie.id.getOrCrash(),
        body: movie.body.getOrCrash(),
        done: movie.done,
        color: movie.color.getOrCrash().value);
  }

  Movie toDomain() {
    return Movie(
        id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id),
        body: MovieBody(body),
        color: MovieColor(Color(color)),
        done: done);
  }

  factory MovieItemDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MovieItemDtoFromJson(json);
}
```

when I am running `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --use-polling-watcher --delete-conflicting-outputs` I am getting the following error:

Cannot populate the required constructor argument: id.

const factory MovieItemDto(
^^^^^^^^^^^